# Overheating Problem?

Tags: resistors, power-dissipation

I have almost no electrical experience, so I apologize about the simplicity of the question in advance.
I have 4 resistors a diode and a transistor in a 22mm x 14mm x 8mm enclosure.
My concern is that the resistors will get too hot considering the tight space.

[image: Front]
[image: Back]

Red/Blk wire is 12volts and Brown wire is Ground.

Schematic:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: We need a circuit diagram to tell you anything. Or at least post a *high-resolution* picture of **both** sides of the board.

Comment: http://i42.tinypic.com/5pn7d3.jpg

Comment: These two pieces of information would help answer your questions better.  (1) What's the power rating of the resistors?  (2) Better characterization of temperatures.  (2.1) More info about the environment this device will operate in (e.g. indoor, outdoor, automotive, satellite, wearable, implantable).  What range of ambient temperatures do you design this device for?  (2.2) What's the max temperature raise (increase in temperature due to normal operation) do you specify?

Comment: I see 4 resistors in the photo but you only have 3 in the schematic.

Comment: @Dean - Yeah. Also, the resistors in the schematic don't correlate with the resistors in the picture. The schematic has the 22K and the 2.7K, but not the 1.8K and 1K.

Comment: 1.8k and 1k in parallel should be 642 ?                 I believe the resistors are 1/4 watt environment will be automotive in cabin. I did not design the device I followed the schematic. I have never seen it in such a small enclosure and was concerned because of what little knowledge I have about electronic components.

Comment: @AlexPetrov The environment is not very hot. The resistors are not underrated (see calculations by Fake Name).  At this point (if it were my project) I wouldn't worry about overheating too much and start testing/using the device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guessing from the picture (you can see the resistor values).

Resistors:

- 1001 - 1K
- 1801 - 1.8K
- 2701 - 2.7K
- 2202 - 22K

The lowest value resistor is 1KΩ.

[Ohm's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohms_law):

\$V = I*R\$ or \$\frac{V}{R}=I\$

\$\frac{12V }{ 1000\Omega }= 12ma\$

Now, Solve for power

\$Volts * Amps = Power\$
\$12V * 0.012A = 0.144W\$
As such, the lowest-value resistor, connected directly across the leads will only produce 0.144W of heat, or 144 mW.

The other resistors will be less.

You will have to decide what "too hot" is. It shouldn't produce that much heat, though.

---

Of course, this is just for the resistors. Your device has a diode and a transistor on it. We can't estimate the power they are dissipating without a schematic, or some sort of documentation.

What is that thing, anyways?

Comment: Thank you for adding the picture to the question. The schematic I have is hand drawn. http://i42.tinypic.com/5pn7d3.jpg This is used to trick the ECU on a car into thinking the EGR is still working.

Comment: Here is what the back looks like. It's a little messy.  http://i43.tinypic.com/6qyxph.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to answer this question might be to put it in the enclosure, power it up on a hot day, and see if it gets too hot.